# Differentiating a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

In numerical mathematics, we looked at the "Taylor series method" to construct one-step methods. Let $\mathbf{\dot{y}} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y})$ be a system of differential equations. We define a family of discrete evolutions by $$\Psi_n^{t,t+h} \mathbf{z} = \mathbf{z} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{h^i}{i!} \Delta_i \mathbf{z},$$ where $\Delta_i \mathbf{z} := \left. \frac{\mathrm d^{i-1}}{\mathrm{d}s^{i-1}} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}(s))\right|_{s=t}$ with $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds} \mathbf{y}(s) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}(s)), \mathbf{y}(t) = \mathbf{z}$.

We now want to express $\Delta_{1,2,3} \mathbf{z}$ depending on $\mathbf{f}$ and its derivatives (we assume the function to be sufficiently smooth). The first one, $\Delta_1 \mathbf{z}$, is easy as it's just $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}(t)) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{z})$. For the second one, we will have to apply the chain rule. This leads me to $\Delta_2 \mathbf{z} = (D \mathbf{f})(\mathbf{z}) \,\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{z})$. The standard solution suggest something slightly different, namely they write $D_\mathbf{y}$ instead of just a $D$. I tried checking the lecture notes and didn't really find anything, so, what exactly does the subscript stand for? What does it change? Also, I am not sure how to interpret this result. Is $D\mathbf{f(z)}$ a $n \times n$ matrix? Because otherwise, the result wouldn't make much sense, would it? Is it simply the Jacobian of $\mathbf{f}$?

Now for the last case, the standard solution suggests $$\Delta_3 \mathbf{z} = (D^2_\mathbf{y} \mathbf{f})(\mathbf{z}) (\mathbf{f(z)},\mathbf{f(z)}) + ((D_\mathbf{y} \mathbf{f})(\mathbf{z}))^2 \,\mathbf{f(z)}.$$ This is an application of the product rule. The second term makes sense, however, I'm not sure about the first term. What does $(\mathbf{f(z)},\mathbf{f(z)})$ stand for? And what is $D^2_\mathbf{y}$? Is it the Hessian matrix? Again, why add the subscript $\mathbf{y}$?

I feel like these are very basic things and I would like to understand them before I keep going. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks a lot in advance.